# Debugging this mapreduce output

Tags: java, hadoop

Question :
you’ve imported your data, you need to write a MapReduce job to to translate the latitude and longitude values into locations and count the users at each location. You have a Java package with a geo.GeoLookup class that includes a toLocation(float lat, float lon) method which returns a location as a String in the form "city, state, country". Which of the following code snippets correctly implements a MapReduce job that will operate on the /user/hive/warehouse/example directory as input and produce a list of all unique locations in the dataset and how many users are associated with each location. Below was a option & it was marked wrong.

```
public static class MapTask
  extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String[] cols = value.toString().split(",");
  String loc =
    geo.GeoLookup.toLocation(Float.parseFloat(cols[3]), Float.parseFloat(cols[4]));

  context.write(new Text(loc), new IntWritable(1));
 }
}

public static class ReduceTask
   extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  IntWritable count = null;

  for (IntWritable value: values) {
   if (count == null) {
    count = value;
   } else {
    count.set(count.get() + value.get());
   }
  }

  context.write(key, count);
 }
}
```

The final count for each distinct location will be 2.
I understand that there is some problem in this assignment

```
count = value;
```

But still i am not understanding how am i getting output as 2 ?

Comment: Which is you question, the first or the second ? and give us sample input and what you get in output.

Comment: I understand its related to reuse of object by hadoop (e.g value). But how do i get output = 2. I thought still its 1

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can give a sample input, expected output and the actual output you got. Then it will be easier for the people to answer.

Comment: `count.set(count.get() + value.get())` will be a very expensive operation. Why not have `count` as a regular `int` and convert it to `IntWritable` just before outputting? Also there's no need for that whole `if/else` part - just initialise `count = 0` instead of `count = null` and then you can simply do `count += value.get()`.